# How do I format specifiers write "for"?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

example code:

```
std::string x = "test %d test %d";

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
 x = x, 1;
}
printf(x);
```

example result: test 1 test 512765712

I want : test 1 test 1

how can I do that?

I change question because people not understand.

```
const char* Test(const char* testx, ...)
{
    char tested[1024 + 1];
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, tested);
    vsnprintf(tested, sizeof(tested), testx, args);
    va_end(args);

    const char* testx(tested);

    return testx;
}

std::string x = "test %d test %d"; // x is changeable. this is example.
int index = 2; // index is changeable. this is example.


for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
 test(x, i)
}

printf(x);
```

result: test 1 test 5125219

I want: test 0 test 1

Comment: try https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to be happening in the line `x = x, 1;`. Are you trying to say "`x` should be the result of substituting in `1` for the first `%d` in `x`"?

Comment: `x = x,1;` is equivalent to `x = x; 1;`, which is equivalent to doing nothing at all. And your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Try this: `printf(x.c_str(), 1, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void solve()
{
    string testString="test";
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout<<testString<<" "<<i<<" "<<testString<<" "<<i<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
test 0 test 0
test 1 test 1
```